# React Router's HashRouter redirects to <base> tag url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, base-url, base-tag

I have non-SPA server-side application with React application that is limited to current page, `/some/static/page`. *The application has `<base href="/">` in `<head>` on all pages and relies on it, this cannot be changed.*

Here is basic example with React 16, React Router 4 and `<HashRouter>`:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Root} />
                </div>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

All routes can be disabled for testing purposes, but this doesn't change the behaviour.

[Here is `create-react-app` project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mrd9ux4tblwruy/react-hash-routing.zip?dl=1) that shows the problem. The steps to replicate it are:

- `npm i`
- `npm start`
- navigate to `http://localhost:3000/some/static/page`

HashRouter is clearly affected by `<base>`. It redirects from `/some/static/page` to `/#/` on initialization, while I expect it to be `/some/static/page#/` or `/some/static/page/#/` (works as intended only in IE 11).

There's a quick splash of `Root` component before it redirects to `/#/`.

It redirects to `/foo/#/` in case of `<base href="/foo">`, and it redirects to `/some/static/page/#/` when `<base>` tag is removed.

**The problem affects Chrome and Firefox (recent versions) but not Internet Explorer (IE 11).**

Why is `<HashRouter>` affected by `<base>`? It's used here exactly because it isn't supposed to affect location path, only hash.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Works as intended only on IE11... well that's a first...

Comment: Please clarify what the intended behaviour is that you want.

Comment: *It redirects from /some/static/page to /#/ on initialization, while I expect it to be /some/static/page#/ or /some/static/page/#/* . I.e. it shouldn't replace `location.pathname` with base url.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually this from `history`. If you see [their code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/e6f9017c947b3ae49affa24cc320d0a86f765b55/packages/react-router-dom/modules/HashRouter.js), they use just `createHashHistory` and set `children`. So it equivalent with this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';

const Root = () => <div>Root route</div>;
export default class App extends React.Component {

  history = createHashHistory({
    basename: "", // The base URL of the app (see below)
    hashType: "slash", // The hash type to use (see below)
    // A function to use to confirm navigation with the user (see below)
    getUserConfirmation: (message, callback) => callback(window.confirm(message)),
  });


  render() {
    return (
      
      <Router history={this.history}>
      <div>Router
        <Route exact path="/" component={Root} />
      </div>
      </Router>
      );
    }
}
```

It will show same issue you have. Then if you change `history` code like this:

```
import {createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

...

history = createBrowserHistory({
    basename: "", // The base URL of the app (see below)
    forceRefresh: false, // Set true to force full page refreshes
    keyLength: 6, // The length of location.key
    // A function to use to confirm navigation with the user (see below)
    getUserConfirmation: (message, callback) => callback(window.confirm(message))
});
```

then your problem will gone but definitely not use `hash`. So the problem not from
`HashRouter` but from `history`.

Because this come from `history`, let's see this [thread](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/94). After read that thread, we can take conclusion this is **feature** from `history`.

so, if you set `<base href="/">`, because you are using `hash` (#), when browser loaded ( actually after `componentDidMount`) it will append `hash` (#) in your case `some/static/page` => `some/static/page` + `/` => `/` + `#/` => `/#/`. You can check in `componentDidMount` set `debugger` to catch before append route.

---

### SOLUTION

simply, just remove element `<base href>` or don't use `HashRouter`.

If still need but want avoid from specific `component`, just put this before `class`:

```
const base = document.querySelector("base");
base.setAttribute('href', '');
```

---

### UPDATE

since you want to keep `base` tag to keep persist link and use `hash` router, here the close solution I think.

**1. Set tag `base` to empty.**

```
const base = document.querySelector('base');
base.setAttribute('href', '');
```

put that code in `App` component (root wrap component) to call once.

**2. When `componentDidMount` set it back**

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    base.setAttribute('href', '/');
  }, 1000);
}
```

using timeout to wait react done render virtual dom.

This is very close, I think (have test it). Because you are using `hash` router, link from index html will safe (not override by react but keep by `base` tag). Also it work with css link `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link to history issue. I'm not sure what [this means](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/94#issuecomment-211475547) for current problem. Should <base> parsing be added to react-router-dom, because history doesn't support that? *simply, just remove element <base href> or don't use HashRouter* - this is not possible. This is non-SPA application where some parts rely on current <base>. I had to temporarily switch to another router that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: if just avoid to react only, last solution will suitable, I think.

Comment: I keep it in mind, thanks. But I suppose this will break assets that can be loaded after React app initialization. There's not much, but they can be there. Due to how <base> works, modifying it would be very destructive move for the website that relies on it.

Comment: @estus, I get it now, see my update for more information

Comment: as my update, the `timeout` will help you. Also I think SSR will help the problem since SSR from server like NextJS (my argue). not sure

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to keep things as straightforward as possible, and random delays have smell. Is it safe to assume that `setTimeout(..., 0)` will work as well? Is setTimeout needed there at all? I guess that in your solution `base.setAttribute('href', '')` goes to `render`? I'm thinking about wrapping HashRouter with HOC for this purpose.

Comment: I think `setTimeout` will help for `async`, since I don't know how big your react app. You can remove it, just put clean ` base.setAttribute('href', '/');` if your react app is simple. HOC, I didn't think that. How do you accomplish with that?

Comment: As regular HOC, wrapped original HashRouter with another component, just to decouple the fix from <App>. Posted it as an answer, in case this helps somebody else. I don't think that the app matters, because the problem arises inside HashRouter, it occurs only on router init which is sync, to my knowledge. I hope there shouldn't be any async issues (at least this works for me).

Comment: Nice to know, simply to get rid

Answer (score 2):

Your observation about `HashRouter` and the `<base>` tag is correct. I filed an issue about the differences in browsers here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/574 and corresponding PR with fix here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/pull/577

In the meantime, I'm not sure about all the routing you need, but if the react app lives entirely under `/some/static/page/`, you can probably make it work with:

`<BrowserRouter basename="/some/static/page">`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to solve the problem. Consider providing links in the answer for your `history` PRs that are supposed to fix this. I will likely make it accepted answer when PRs are merged.

Comment: Thanks! The currently accepted answer is an immediate solution to your question so no worries about changing it.

Answer (score 2):

I ended with HOC that simply applies a fix described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49540274/3731501) :

```
function withBaseFix(HashRouter) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.baseElement = document.querySelector('base');
            if (this.baseElement) {
                this.baseHref = this.baseElement.getAttribute('href');
                this.baseElement.setAttribute('href', '');
            }
        }

        render() {
            return <HashRouter {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</HashRouter>;
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            if (this.baseElement)
                this.baseElement.setAttribute('href', this.baseHref);
        }
    }
};

const FixedHashRouter = withBaseFix(HashRouter);

...
<FixedHashRouter>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Root} />
    </div>
</FixedHashRouter>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base#Hint, it says that using `<base>` even with #target URLs is expected behavior.

And on https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter it says in basename: string section: A properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but *no trailing slash*.

So maybe you should define a different basename on the `HashRouter` element or remove the trailing slash from `<base>`

Comment: Are you suggesting to replace `<base href="/">` with `<base href="">`? It will defy the purpose, won't it? HashRouter documentation also states that `basename` is base url for hash, not for entire location path, see the example with `<HashRouter basename="/calendar"/>` there. If you have different information, please, provide it.

Comment: Yes `<base href="">` defies the purpose, but with the current behavior it seems to be a solution. However, `<base>` and `basename` are different, so a better solution might be to keep both `basename = ""` and `<base href = "/">`.

Comment: @estus. Yes, `basename` is base url for hash, not entire location path, but the question is not using it. It uses only `<base>`

Comment: <base href=""> cannot be a solution because this will break website assets that relies on it (I updated the question to state this explicitly). basename didn't work for me, it affects hash part only, as the documentation suggests. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue of [`history`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) package. It is even resolved, please look at [this pr](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/pull/578)

As a temporary fix I suggest you to just specify this branch in `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "history": "git://github.com/amuzalevskiy/history.git",
  ...
}
```

And once fix will be merged into original branch - revert this back to fixed main npm module

---

Regarding repo:
I just did `npm run build` on the [microbouji solution](https://github.com/microbouji/history/tree/fix-base-tag-hashHistory-createHref) and commited result, as it is impossible to use original repository without running `publish` script

Comment: Thanks. This works, although I prefer to avoid using hotfixes from unmerged PRs because in case they are discarded or abandoned, I end up with unmaintained fork.

Comment: @estus Ok... Personal opinion - keep main code clean and open corresponding PR, usefull for community. And also often "fixing main code to use buggy library" is like a snowball which grows day after day, and at some point it will be easier to stay on older version, than update library, because nobody knows where fixes are :-)